# Can an xts object be created from a list?

Tags: r, xts

I would like to apply the `xts` class to a list.

```
y <- list(1, 2, 3)
tm <- Sys.time() + 1:3
require(xts)
xts(x = y, order.by = tm)
## Error in coredata.xts(x) : currently unsupported data type
```

Fair enough, is it fairly straightforward to extend this so that I can make this work for my own (extension of list) class?  Do I write methods for `coredata`, `index` and `xts` that apply to my own class or do I need to first add similar methods for `list`?

I couldn't find anything in the documentation or vignettes on this, but I'm probably missing something obvious.

Primarily I would like to create a simple class based on a recursive vector, and then apply the `xts` tools of `index` and `[` to that. The extraction tools allow indexing by time interval with simple character strings, i.e. ["2013-05-31 10"] means the interval between 10:00:00 and 10:59:59 on that day and this is the feature I'd like to get `for free`.

Comment: No, this is not straightforward. Can you expand on what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exploring the source code shows that this is really not possible without substantial work (as Joshua says in the comment above).

The code that provides the general support for input types is in C in xts, so that alone makes it extra effort to apply this outside of atomic vectors, matrices and data.frames.

The analogous code in `zoo` is pure R so that could work a little more easily, but I wanted the support that allows indexing by time interval with simple character strings, i.e. ["2013-05-31 10"] means the interval between 10:00:00 and 10:59:59 on that day.

The best options I can see are

1. Poach or recreate the code for time interval indexing and apply to the new class
2. Create an object containing `xts` and define methods to propagate the support to the recursive list component. (There are examples of this in an overall S4 context, e.g. in `spacetime`.)

Answer (score 0):

An xts object is (in essence) a numerical matrix plus an index attribute.

The constraints are hence a) to have a numeric matrix (which you know how to create from a list) and b) to have a `POSIXt` object for the index.

If you are beholden to lists, keep your data as a list of ... xts objects.